# Talend - getCode() error while extracting XML file

Tags: xml, talend

I am using Talend and I am trying to extract some data from an XML file with a tMap in order to store them in a MySQL database.

But I get this error: (screenshot)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJqDE.jpg

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: the (french) screenshot is complitely without context, useless at most. Which code did you use in your tMap? Can you post a screenshot of your entire job, too?

Comment: Hi, the french error says: "Double entry method getCode() in the type test1.row1Struct"

The job: http://i.imgur.com/YWhQOXE.jpg

The tMap scheme: http://i.imgur.com/FgzlDon.jpg - There is no code in the tMap, a simple mapping.

Comment: + I'm starting to believe the problem comes when extracting the data from the XML file. When I extracted only three fields, it worked without errors. But I'll need to work after with the all the fileds of the XML file after.

Comment: Hello, I finally found the problem. Talend generated the method getCode() twice. Now how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Try to regenerate the code. Just move a component a bit, save, and execute again. Sometimes you even need to close the job and open it up again to make things work. If nothing helps, throw away the faulty component and take a new one.

Comment: Just curiosity. What version of Talend are you using?